# Estimating client-side font-rendering-size on the server?

Tags: javascript, python, fonts

I have a web site with comments; each comment could be a variable length. Longer comments naturally take up more space. However, I only have a finite amount of space on the page to put these comments.

Naturally, picking a fixed number of comments out of the stack doesn't work, because they could be short 1 liners or 50 line essays. Sending the whole list down to the client, and having the client javascript cut it to the appropiate length after rendering, looks hopelessly wasteful. Counting characters doesn't work, because "iii" takes up much less space than "MMM"

What I want is some way to calculate the height of each comment given it's content, the font, font size and weight. Even if it's not perfect, I can just fudge the server to send, perhaps, 20% too many comments and have the client javascript trim it down, which will at least bound my wastage to some fraction of the comments.

I'm using Python, and was considering having Python Image Library render the comment text on the server and seeing how tall/wide the final image is. First, though, is there any "standard" way of doing this?

EDIT: I could also render each character and maintain a mapping of character, font, weight, size -> width, height on the server, since I'm not dabbling in kerning or other inter-character relationships.

Comment: Have you considered formatting each comment with CSS: `overflow-y: auto;` (also specify a height) such that they won't stretch for long comments and break the layout, but will display a scrollbar if necessary so your users can still read all of any long comments.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I'd rather not do that; I think scrollbars are ugly (at least microsoft windows scrollbars are ugly) and go against the visual design of the site. I could scroll each comment, or scroll the whole list of comments, but the ideal is I do not scroll at all =)

Answer (score 1):

You should remember the law of large numbers. Not many essays are composed of just letter i or M. Try some real comment text first, the character counting could work better than you expected. Also it is much faster than using PIL to render your text serverside.

Comment: I probably will try doing that, along with the character-by-character numerical method I mentioned, but I was hoping there was some canonical way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really coarse, ascii-only estimate that's still better than character-counting, you can try these per-character widths I just generated for my project:

```
{" ": 0.328, "!": 0.381, "\"": 0.475, "#": 0.655, "$": 0.655, "%": 1.069,
"&": 0.9, "'": 0.347, "(": 0.414, ")": 0.414, "*": 0.555, "+": 0.713,
",": 0.328, "-": 0.414, ".": 0.328, "/": 0.346, "0": 0.655, "1": 0.655,
"2": 0.655, "3": 0.655, "4": 0.655, "5": 0.655, "6": 0.655, "7": 0.655,
"8": 0.655, "9": 0.655, ":": 0.346, ";": 0.346, "<": 0.713, "=": 0.713,
">": 0.713, "?": 0.619, "@": 1.201, "A": 0.864, "B": 0.829, "C": 0.862,
"D": 0.897, "E": 0.793, "F": 0.724, "G": 0.931, "H": 0.897, "I": 0.381,
"J": 0.55, "K": 0.864, "L": 0.726, "M": 1.071, "N": 0.897, "O": 0.931,
"P": 0.758, "Q": 0.931, "R": 0.862, "S": 0.758, "T": 0.759, "U": 0.897,
"V": 0.864, "W": 1.173, "X": 0.864, "Y": 0.864, "Z": 0.759, "[": 0.381,
"\\": 0.346, "]": 0.381, "^": 0.583, "_": 0.655, "`": 0.347, "a": 0.619,
"b": 0.655, "c": 0.585, "d": 0.655, "e": 0.619, "f": 0.381, "g": 0.655,
"h": 0.655, "i": 0.312, "j": 0.312, "k": 0.621, "l": 0.312, "m": 1.0,
"n": 0.655, "o": 0.655, "p": 0.655, "q": 0.655, "r": 0.414, "s": 0.55,
"t": 0.346, "u": 0.655, "v": 0.621, "w": 0.897, "x": 0.621, "y": 0.621,
"z": 0.585, "{": 0.509, "|": 0.285, "}": 0.509, "~": 0.698}
```

[This is a small writeup](https://pschanely.github.io/2022/04/11/relative-per-character-widths.html) about how I made them.